# Can I use "WAITFOR DELAY" to execute a procedure

Tags: t-sql

I'm wondering if it's possible to execute a procedure inside the same procedure. I wouldn't like to use a trigger so what I'm trying to do is to execute the same procedure in a loop if condition is false after 10 minutes.

```
use CF_BPS
go

create procedure p_Monitoring_HLR_statusy
as

if (
(select sum(uruchom_api) as sprawdzenie from ANALIZY..CC_LISTA_SMS_API
where priorytet=0 and cast(aud_data as date)=cast(getdate() as   
date))=0)    

begin

        insert into [CF_BPS].[dbo].[Monitoring_HLR_statusy]
        ([sp_id], [sp_numer], [tn_numer], [sms_api_check_date], [sms_api_phone], [sms_api_status])

        select [sp_id], [sp_numer], [telefon], [sms_api_check_date], [sms_api_phone], [sms_api_status] from ANALIZY..CC_LISTA_SMS_API
        where priorytet=0 and cast(aud_data as date)=cast(getdate() as date)

end

    else

begin

        waitfor delay '00:10:00.000'
        execute p_Monitoring_HLR_statusy

end
```

go

Comment: why not a job scheduled every 10 minutes?

Comment: But I don't want a job to start every 10 min all the time, I'd like to stop it if condition is true. CanI do it using a job?

Comment: yes, if you don't want the job to run again you can use sp_stop_job

Comment: That's what I want.

Comment: sp_stop_job procedure stops executing running job but it doesn't alter the fact that the job will fire according to the schedule.

Comment: I'd like the job to be stopped if the condition is true and be executed the next day accoring to the schedule until the condition is true.

Comment: You might check sp_update_schedule and change the active_end_date  of the job not to run. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-update-schedule-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: The code you've posted seems like it should work, but it's very likely to cause a stackoverflow exception if the condition is not met within a fair amount of attempts. This is a recursive process, beware of infinite recursion. A scheduled job is probably a better solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to avoid the recursion issue, and to just make the logic more transparent, I'd break this into two pieces. In SQL Agent, this is dead simple. Probably not much harder in any other scheduling tool.

First, have the job execute your procedure. Instead of the `WAITFOR`, though, have the `ELSE` clause `THROW` an error. (Note the semi-colon after `BEGIN`; it's a requirement for `THROW`.)

Then set up your job scheduler to retry the failed job after a 10 minute delay, and set a limit for the number of retries so you don't accidentally put yourself in a situation where the job just keeps trying even if your data never shows up.

The revised proc looks like this:

```
use CF_BPS
go

create procedure p_Monitoring_HLR_statusy
as

if (
(select sum(uruchom_api) as sprawdzenie from ANALIZY..CC_LISTA_SMS_API
where priorytet=0 and cast(aud_data as date)=cast(getdate() as   
date))=0)  

    begin;

      insert into [CF_BPS].[dbo].[Monitoring_HLR_statusy]
      ([sp_id], [sp_numer], [tn_numer], [sms_api_check_date], [sms_api_phone], [sms_api_status])

      select [sp_id], [sp_numer], [telefon], [sms_api_check_date], [sms_api_phone], [sms_api_status] from ANALIZY..CC_LISTA_SMS_API
      where priorytet=0 and cast(aud_data as date)=cast(getdate() as date);

    end

  else

    begin;

      THROW 51000, 'The data does not exist yet.', 1;

    end
```

Comment: I'm of opinion that it's a little bit confusing that "Retry Attempts" feature is below "On success action" section. How is this feature supposed to work?

Comment: Yes, that tab isn't very intuitive. Once you've set it up a couple of times, though, it's easy to remember. Just select the number of minutes to wait between retries (in your case, you want a ten minute wait), and then select the number of times you want it to retry. It sounds like you want that to be a pretty large number. Here's a short blog post with a corresponding screen shot: https://sqldbpool.com/2014/06/01/how-to-rerun-the-sql-agent-job-step-automatically-in-case-of-failure/